# How can I position the page after a redirect?

Tags: php, redirect

Well, the problem is that I have a redirect link which works fine, it redirects me to a page with listed items (1. How to buy, 2. How to pay, etc.).

My question is, is there anyway of setting the page in a specific item so the user wont have to scroll down to get there?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried html anchors ? Or javascript ? Have you tried anything yet ? ^^

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @TheBlueDog while i hate a bad question i dont think this falls into that category.. He/she DID as a genuine question.. doesnt show any effort in research but the question is valid and makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, i dont know why was downvoted, now I cant even upvote the answers that I like cause of reputation... Anyway, thanks, anchors works fine.

Comment: @TheBlueDog that your comment was premature. Thats all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Anchors.  Details on this site
http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html

Basically you name the place you want to jump to with

```
 <a name="mySection" />
```

Then on your link, you refer to it to

```
 <a href="page.html#mySection>Go to my section </a>
```

Comment: Because some people just downvotes everything to make themselves feel good about their day...

Comment: lol, no idea, its the right answer :) I upvoted it the OP needs to redirect with an anchor in it, like linking to this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Statistics

Comment: Hmmm, maybe because the HTML5 way is to use the ID attribute instead of the name attribute? http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#anchors-with-id

Comment: and what about legacy @j08691 .. ? Thats not a reason for a correct answer being downvoted. But yeah,, it should be ID :D

Comment: @Pogrindis - Who said I was the downvoter? And it was recommended since HTML4.

Comment: @j08691 i was just suprised to see downvote on it, but you're wrong in saying its the html5 way.. :) its the `way` id's are reccomended

Comment: SO is becoming like Reddit where people fight and downvote about the most stupid thing..

Comment: Nothing is stupid if it gets resolved.. dont compare SO to reddit or i will downvote! :D

Comment: @Pogrindis - Explain to me how I'm wrong that it's the HTML5 way.

Comment: @j08691 quite simple.. using id was not introduced in HTML5.. therefore it inherited this.. Ergo.. NOT HTML5 way. Although i hate that expression.. Angular way too .. While there is merit to it, use it for HTML5 features

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1. Use an anchor in the URL and `a name` in the HTML
2. query parameters with JavaScript

JS:

```
//The URL would become:
var redirectURL = "http://mystore.com/somepage/?product=13";

//On the page, you'd have JavaScript that gets the parameter and scrolls to that object
var product = getParameterByName( "product" );

//Now scroll to it
scrollTo( 0, getLocationOnPageByProductId( product ) );

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

If using anchors, it would be:

```
var redirectURL = "http://mystore.com/somepage/#product13";

<a name="product13"></a><div>the product</div>
```